# Previously created SQLite Database can not be accessed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, mobile-application

I am creating an application in which I have to open a previously created SQLite Database. I am using a DBHelper class. Everything is fine when I am emulating the app, but the logcat is showing the following error:

```
10-31 17:59:56.345: I/Database(391): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
10-31 17:59:56.345: E/Database(391): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.proj.neuroq/databases/quiz.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
```

**My Activity class:**

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {

    String db_name="quiz";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
        myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDatabase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_question, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

**My DatabaseHelper class:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.proj.neuroq/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "quiz.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     */
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist) {
            //do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it dosen't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        }

        if(checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(db != null)
            db.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**My manifest file:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.proj.neuroq"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".QuestionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_question" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is my project structure:**

[image: Project Structure **quiz.db** in **assets**]

This is my **logcat output:**

[image: **Logcat** error]

The links I had referred:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=58589

Where lies the tricky issue?

Comment: This error message is shown by checkDataBase() function. This will show only once when checking for already existing database

Comment: Its showing everytime I emulate

Comment: you are not calling createDatabase() function in DatabaseHelper() constructor

Comment: Yes obviously, its given in the snapshot

Comment: can you tell me the size of your quiz.db file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937791/sqlite-problem-within-eclipse-not-recognizing-db-file Is this similar to your problem ? Does this help you ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your checkDataBase() method with something like this:

```
public boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

as suggested in this article: http://www.itsalif.info/content/check-if-database-exist-android-sqlite3openv2-failed